# Position relative is being blocked

Tags: css, flexbox

Trying to use the position:relative to move my logo to the left of my page. However, when I move it by 20px it doesn't budge but when I move it 300px to the bottom it disappears.

This is how my code is currently looking:

```
.container-header {
    justify-content: flex-end;
    display: flex;
    padding-bottom: 20px;

}
nav{
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

a{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    color: black;
    margin: 20px;
}

img {
    position: relative;
    left: 40px; 
}
```

Any suggestions as to why it isn't working?

Comment: You need to add some HTML to this example.

Answer (score 0):

Use "margin-left" instead of "left" :

```css
img{
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 40px
}
```

I advise you to make a "div" around your img for have a better control on the position,
Hope it will help